Quantum Mechanical Current Normalisation
Consider an electron leaving a metal. The quantum-mechanical current operator, is given (Landau and Lifshitz, 1974) by
$$
j_x\left[\psi_{\mathrm{f}}\right]=\frac{\hbar i}{2 m}\left(\psi_{\mathrm{f}} \frac{\partial \psi_{\mathrm{f}}^*}{\partial x}-\psi_{\mathrm{f}}^* \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}\right)
$$
where $\psi_{\mathrm{f}}$ is the time-independent wave function of the electron in its final state, $\psi_{\mathrm{f}}^*$ is the complex conjugate function to $\psi_{\mathrm{f}}$, and $i=\sqrt{-1}$.
Assume the 1D Schrödinger holds:
$$
\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{p^2}{\hbar^2}-\frac{2 m}{\hbar^2} V(x)\right] \psi(x)=0
$$
Assume that $\mathscr{L}(p)$ is independent of $x$, and $f(x, p)$ is the solution of the Schrödinger equation, which, as $x \rightarrow \infty$, describes the electron wave propagating from the metal surface and is normalized by the condition $j_x[f]=p / m$.
What does this normalization condition mean? I don't understand the why that is a constraint/reasonable assumption here.

What is $\mathscr{L}$?

@Andrew I read that equation so that it is meant for positive eigenvalue solutions, and $p^2/\hbar^2$ is a peculiar notation for $2mE/\hbar^2$. But I may be wrong...

Normalization essentially means that the factor in fron of the wave function is such that you get p/m number of particles per unit square per sec. This should be the case.

That is not the Schrödinger equation. It reduces to $V\psi =0$.

There is also a factor $e$ missing in the current operator. You should use the subscript f consistently. Better still, drop it.

Wgat does the notation $j_x\left[\psi_{\mathrm{f}}\right]$ mean? Unless you have a very good reason, stick to the expressions and notations commonly found in good textbooks.

Well, the Schroedinger equation for $\psi$ is always kind of the same; the potential energy or the number of kinetic terms changes, but otherwise the form
$$
\hat{H}\psi = E\psi
$$
remains. But the meaning and interpretation of $\psi$ can be more variable (as can be seen in the Landau&Lifshitz book Quantum Mechanics).
For bound states of single or few particles in a potential, or interacting among themselves, we often use the symbol $\psi$ in the sense that $\int_{\tau}|\psi|^2~d\tau$ is probability that the configuration of the system is somewhere in the region $\tau$. Then $\psi$ has to be normalized in such a way so that probability of the system being found at any point of the whole configuration space is unity:
$$
\int_{config.~space} |\psi|^2~d\tau = 1.
$$
But if we have a stream of particles moving in space with constant intensity, so that downstream, we expect to be able to detect one particle after another, with constant average rate, it is interesting to re-define $\psi$ as description of that stream, not of just one particle. Then, the integral $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \psi^*\psi~ dx$ may give expected number of particles in the interval $x_1..x_2$. Assuming the stream goes to infinity with unchanged density(infinite number of particles on infinite line), we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*\psi ~dx = \infty.
$$
So $\psi$ with this new meaning intentionally does not have the standard normalization to unity. Instead, the normalization is such that $\psi^*\psi$ gives number of particles per unit of length, e.g. per meter.
This can be demonstrated on the function $e^{ipx/\hbar}$. When our so-defined $\psi$ has this value at all $x$, this implies one particle with momentum $p$ per unit length (moving in free space, with potential the same everywhere). When we plug this psi function into definition of $j_x$, we get
$$
j_x = \frac{p}{m}.
$$
So that $j_x$ has the value of particle velocity.
More generally, if we have $N$ particles per unit length in free space, the psi function is $\psi = N e^{ipx/\hbar}$ and $j_x = N\frac{p}{m}$.
In presence of a potential energy function varying with $x$, the correct psi function (solving the Schr. equation) is no longer proportional to $e^{ipx/\hbar}$ everywhere, but for unbound solutions $\psi$ with high enough energy, far from the region where $V(x)$ varies a lot, things should be similar to the above.

You just need to normalise your solution to unity, after correcting your expressions. The meaning of this is known as the Born rule.
